# How do I make a checkout ui extension text input field only avaliable to customers with a certain tag?

Tags: shopify, shopify-app, shopify-api

I need to create a text input field via checkout UI extensions, but I'd like the input field to only be visible to customers with a certain tag. If anyone could help guide me in the right direction to making a text input field only visible to customers with a certain tag, that would be really appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

You have access to the Customer and that customer's tags in Checkout. Naturally, you could then install a wee bit of business logic in your function to match those tags you find to the ones that dictate your business logic.

What were you expecting?